# Toastr Notification not working inside of success function ( Angular JS 1.6.6 )

Tags: angularjs, toastr

For some reason, when I  am trying to create toastr notifications inside of the below data service success function, they are not working, but if I take them out of that they are.. Any ideas why and how to fix this? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular 1.6 doesn't have success function: Use it like below:

```
$http({
            url: urlToServer,
            method: "POST",
            //cache: false,
            data: jQuery.param(dataObj),
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).then(function (res){
          alert("success", "Hoorey", "Verified");
        },function (error){
          alert("warning", "Oops!", "Could NOT Login");
       });
```